# Traduction de « equate the components/entries » dans un contexte mathématique

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques

Comment traduire « equate the components/entries » d'un bidule mathématique (telle les entrées d'une matrice, les termes d'un polynôme, ...), comme dans l'exemple illustré ci-dessous ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comme le dit @Stéphane_Gimenez *rendre égal* n'aurait pas ici le sens que tu veux. Pour les calculs que tu proposes, le terme que j'emploie — et celui que j'ai l'habitude d'entendre — est *identifier*. S'il fallait un commentaire pour ce calcul, je dirais précisément « On décompose l'équation vectorielle en identifiant les deux vecteurs composantes par composante. » ou éventuellement « coordonnée par coordonnée ».

Comment: J’éviterais de dire « décomposer composante par composante », qui est pléonastique. Je dirais soit « on décompose l’équation », soit « en réécrivant l’équation composante par composante ».

Comment: Bôf, on pourrait décomposer autrement. Et quand bien même, quand j'explique des maths (et c'est mon boulot) ça ne me dérange pas d'être pléonastique ; le but c'est d'être compris. Si je veux vraiment faire concis, l'équation seule suffit.

Comment: Je déconseille l'utilisation d'*identifier*, ou en tout cas il faut être conscient que le sens habituel de « identifier *x* et *y* » c'est « trouver où/qui est *x* et trouver où/qui est *y* ».

Comment: Je ne sais pas pour toi, mais quand je dis *identifier* en maths c'est très souvent pour dire que les coefficients de polynômes égaux sont égaux ou ce genre de chose à base de familles libres, mais jamais pour dire *chercher*.

Comment: @Evpok: En faisant une recherche sur google avec *identifier*, et quelques noms courants de variables, j'ai constaté que le vrai sens de identifier reste largement le plus courant.

Answer (score 3):

En français on « pose une équation » ou on « écrit (ou obtient) une égalité ». Il n'y a pas de verbe similaire a *equate* qui aurait pour signification « placer  de part et d'autre d'un signe égal ». *Comparer* serait le verbe le plus proche, mais on l'utiliserait plus volontiers dans le cas d'une inégalité.

*Égaliser*, *égaler* ou *rendre égal* ont des connotations différentes. *Égaliser* n'est généralement pas utilisé en mathématiques et signifie « (se) positionner au même niveau » ou « rendre uniforme ». Au football par exemple une équipe peut égaliser, et avec un sens très différent, la pelouse aussi peut être égalisée. *Égaler* c'est grosso modo *valoir* : « Sa ruse égale son ambition ». *Rendre égal* c'est en général changer un paramètre pour obtenir deux valeurs identiques.

Dans le cas mentionné, la terminologie que tu recherches est « décomposer une équation ».